# 1x8gb or 2x4gb for Fujitsu Lifebook E8420?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, laptop, memory

http://sp.ts.fujitsu.com/dmsp/publications/public/ds-lifebook-e8420.pdf

> C2D P8700 2.53GHz
>   DDR3
>   supported capacity RAM (max.)  4 GB
>   Memory notes   8 GB - with future memory modules.

For **compatibility**: Is it safer to buy 2x4gb than 1x8gb?
May 1x8gb risk not working?

(Speed-wise, from what I've read, it seems it shouldn't be much difference.)

Will run windows 10, or 7, or Vista (which it has currently).

Comment: Your motherboard does not support 8 GB modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fujitsu Lifebook E8420 supports maximum 8 GB ( 2 x 4 GB)

"Memory notes 8 GB - with future memory modules." - When this laptop was released, 2 GB of DDR3 1066 MHz modules were supported / available. 4 GB modules will be supported in the future is the meaning. It will support 4 GB on each slot now.

Refer this link for compatible upgrades.
http://www.memorystock.com/memory/FujitsuLifeBookE8420.html